# OAuth C# 1.0 Etsy API

Tags: c#, oauth, etsy

Using OAuth, I am trying to authenticate a web forms project to Etsy's API. For more info, read obtaining necessary credentials:

http://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth

In the code below, my authorization URL returns:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?oauth_token=xyz
```

When I visit it in the browser, I receive an error about a missing signature. I assume that my URL is incorrect. The  Etsy documentation says I should obtain the login url parameter. How do I get it from my code?

```
var consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
{
    SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
    ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
    UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true
};

var session = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, 
    "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r",
    "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token",
    "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token");

IToken requestToken = session.GetRequestToken();
string authorisationUrl = session.GetUserAuthorizationUrlForToken(requestToken);
link1.NavigateUrl = authorisationUrl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the wrong URLs as the third and fourth arguent for OAuthSession:

```
        public string GetAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        var consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ConsumerKey = m_ConsumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = m_ConsumerKeySecret,
            UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true
        };

        var session = CreateSession();

        requestToken = session.GetRequestToken();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["EtsyRequestToken"] = requestToken;
        return session.GetUserAuthorizationUrlForToken(requestToken);
    }

OAuthSession CreateSession()
    {
        OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            ConsumerKey = m_ConsumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = m_ConsumerKeySecret,
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1
        };

        OAuthSession session = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=transactions_r",

"https://www.etsy.com/oauth/signin",

"https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token");
        session.CallbackUri = new Uri(m_ReturnUri);
        return session;
    }
```

I used WEB API. Here are the libraries I used:

```
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="RestSharp" version="104.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Comment: What Oauth package are you using for this?  I am killing myself trying to figure out how to make calls against etsy api using ASP.NET webPages C#

Comment: Hi, I used this code: http://pastebin.com/bUiRwDr4 I am willing to sell you a library that pulls orders from Etsy and parses them into strongly typed classes. Please contact me to discuss.

Comment: thanks!  We are not looking to manage orders, but if things change I will email you.   Right now the goal is just to be able to sync listings between mysql and etsy.  Pretty much publish, and update existing MySQL records from an e-commerce site to etsy listings.